# no notification for chat response

Tags: support, chat, notifications, responses

I have a chat room and I was wondering why there are no notifications in the notification/inbox like the ones we get when we receive response to our questions?

Can the notifications be received only on desktop?

Answer (score 6):

You will receive notification of chat replies in your inbox after a sufficiently long period (15-20 minutes), provided you don't acknowledge them by clearing the notification in the chat window or sending new messages.

An overview of what factors come into play when determining if you receive an inbox notification for a chat message can be found in [this post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/938/what-are-the-rules-for-when-chat-messages-appear-in-a-users-inbox/939#939):

> To use you as an example:
>
> 1. @TonyMeyer, i.e. an exact match will cause a notification if you've
>      been in the room in the past seven days.
> 2. @Tony, i.e. a first name
>      match (to be precise, a word boundary match) will cause a notification
>      if you've been in the room in the past two days.
> 3. @Ton will notify you
>      if you've been in the room in the past two days and there's no other
>      user for whom this would be a better match, e.g. someone called "Ton"
>      who has been there within the past seven days (that's 1.) or someone
>      called "Ton Ynnuf" who has been there within the past two days (that's
>      2.).
> 4. An explicit reply to one of your messages (like this one) will always
>      cause a notification.
>
> In addition, these notifications will only be delivered to your global
>   inbox if you haven't seen them within a reasonable amount of time (~20
>   minutes), where "seen" is defined as one of the following:
>
> - visiting a direct permalink to the message in question,
> - acknowledging it through clicking the little number that's popping up on you profile
>     picture in the chat room when you have replies,
> - or saying something in
>     the room in question.

Comment: I guess I did not add the `@` that is why it was not notifying the person. Thanks @Tim