# Chat notifications are broken for the new top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, notifications, top-bar

### *Update*:

This was originally posted as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), but further investigation leads me to believe that this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Chat notifications are allegedly supposed to appear in the top bar after [15-20 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153322/no-notification-for-chat-response/153323#153323), but this behavior is currently not working **for the new top bar**.

To confirm this, BoltClock originally [waited 40 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210072/bring-back-chat-notifications-to-the-top-bar#comment673318_210075) to see if he would get a notification. He did not. As an added test to double confirm it, he then pinged me and I [waited over 60 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210072/bring-back-chat-notifications-to-the-top-bar#comment673326_210075) and had the same results: no notification on the new top bar.

While browsing around waiting, I did notice something: **notifications still work on the old top bar**. Currently, the [Area 51 proposals page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) still has the old top bar. I have a notification there:

[image: Area 51 proposals page]

The [Area 51 *Discuss* page](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) has the new top bar rolled out. No notification in sight there:

[image: Area 51 discuss page]

I tried multiple pages with the new top bar with plenty of hard refreshes. The message *does* get listed in my inbox, but there is no notification for it on the *new* top bar:

[image: my inbox]

---

### *Original Post*:

As [pointed out in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12483343#12483343) by someone else, there is no longer a notification icon in the top bar when someone pings me in a chat room.

There will only be a notification if I'm in a chat room, or the classic "chat top bar" notification icon will appear once I visit a chat page:

[image: chat notification screenthot]

I think removing this from the (non-chat) top bar is a step in the wrong direction. Can we have that back?

Comment: I've always received chat notifications in the new top bar while it was on meta...

Comment: Chat messages don't show up in your inbox for 20 minutes, to give you a chance to see them in chat first.  The behavior on this hasn't changed at all.  Am I missing something else?

Comment: @Nick I never noticed there was a delay, I guess I am just as slow as the notifications are :)

Comment: Actually, the old top bar had the same bug (if I understand your situation correctly). Chat notifications appear in the inbox after a delay but the inbox count is not updated, you need to refresh the page for the count to be updated or appear.

Comment: @Gilles correct, there's a delay. But, notifications were not showing up _at all_. [It's fixed now, though](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210072/chat-notifications-are-broken-for-the-new-top-bar#comment673631_210075 "@JohnB ah there was an eventing problem here after all due to the fact chat messages register via the api - fix rolling out now.").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting this as an answer so other see it:

The behavior here hasn't changed.  Chat messages have approximately a 20 minute delay (so they can be seen in chat) before notifying you of something *you missed*. The same inbox behavior remains intact with no tweaks in the new top bar.

Comment: Thanks, [here's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153323/216955 "no notification for chat response") Tim's detailed explanation on how the notifications work for anyone interested

Comment: So I just tested this, had OP ping me in the Teachers' Lounge. It shows up in my inbox, but there is no indicator of any new, unread inbox items, not even after well over twice the estimated delay.

Comment: I believe @Bolt was vacant from the chat for more than 25 minutes (I forgot to check the timestamps). We're currently testing it further, I'll give it an hour or so this time

Comment: 40 minutes thereabouts :P

Comment: Waited over an hour, still no notification on the _new_ top bar. See my updated post for an interesting twist

Comment: @JohnB ah there was an eventing problem here after all due to the fact chat messages register via the api - fix rolling out now.

Comment: Works for me now, Thanks!

Comment: @Nick is this [broken again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214526/152859)?